# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datetime

I tried to save a login record to SQL Server.

But I get an error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line of code when `Login.aspx` is running.

What is wrong in these codes ?

My table `Login`:

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Url] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Count] [int] NOT NULL,
[PcName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Browser] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[IpAddress] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
```

C#  code:

```
    SqlConnection conn= "...";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Logins();
    }

    public void Logins()
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Application["hit"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["hit"].ToString());
        }

        string strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

        string page = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);
        string browser = Request.Browser.Browser;
        string pcname = Convert.ToString(ipEntry.HostName);

        String IP = "";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://checkip.dyndns.org/");

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            IP = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        int first = IP.IndexOf("Address: ") + 9;
        int last = IP.LastIndexOf("</body>");

        IP = IP.Substring(first, last - first);

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Login(Url, Time, Count, Browser, PcName, IpAddress) values (@Url, @Time, @Count, @Browser, @PcName, @IpAddress)";

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Url", page.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Count", Convert.ToInt32(Application["hit"].ToString()));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Browser", browser.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PcName", pcname.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IpAddress", IP.Trim());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Check for the date first. If it is incorrect date like 30 of february you will get that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Time", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Solved.I changed DateTime.Now.ToString to DateTime.Now.Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**Problem 1:** You are sending the String to the DateTime parameter `Time`.

**Solution 1:** You need to pass the `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to the `Time` parameter

**Problem 2:** You are missing the `@` symbol infront of parameters in `AddWithValue()` function.

**Solution 2:** You need to add the `@` symbol infront of the parameters in `AddWithValue()` function.

Try This:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", page.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Count",
      Convert.ToInt32(Application["hit"].ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Browser", browser.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PcName", pcname.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IpAddress", IP.Trim());
```

Comment: Solved.I changed DateTime.Now.ToString to DateTime.Now.Thank you